# How to preallocate objects in C++ instead of using new?

Tags: c++, xml, new-operator, xerces-c

A piece of C++ I've been asked to look at is performing poorly due to an inordinate number of invocations of "new" on objects we use to store information about a node in an XML DOM tree. I've verified that new is the cause, using both AQTime and Very Sleepy profilers.

These objects all contain several other object types and pointers to objects as members, so each new on a node object will invoke the constructors of all the member objects as well, which I guess is the reason each allocation takes so long. It also means we can't just call something like GlobalAlloc and request a big chunk of memory - it needs to be initialised afterwards.

I've been investigating using preallocation techniques to mitigate this poor performance, but the ones I've seen involve requesting big chunks of uninitialised memory which isn't suitable for what I need, while others ultimately end up calling new anyway, cancelling out any performance gain we might observe so I'm wondering if there is another option I'm unaware of? I have a feeling what I'm asking for can't be done, that it's either retrieving uninitialised memory quickly or initialised memory slowly. Please prove me wrong :)

Thanks

Comment: Well you can't get around initialisation, so why not allocate a large chunk and build a custom allocator? That's about all you can do.

Comment: Two questions:  1. Speaking of "initialized memory slowly," does the memory not have to be initialized before use in any event?  2.  Thinking of the objects whose allocation is slowing execution, are all, or most, of these objects the same size?  In other words, irrespective of considerations of speed, could you conveniently allocate them in an array if you wanted to?

Comment: If there was a faster way to allocate objects, with no cost or trade-off whatsoever, then your C++ implementation would probably already use it. Your question doesn't describe *any* price that you're able to pay for faster performance of the object initialization. So where do you think that an improvement could possibly come from? Maybe you need to create fewer objects. "pointers to objects" cost almost nothing to initialize, but if you're allocating something to go on the end of those pointers, maybe that could be replaced by a member of the type pointed to.

Comment: The question is too general. Give us some code example.

Comment: @SteveJessop Creating fewer objects is something I am looking into as well. Our XML parsing process is quite involved as we use Xerces-C to parse the document and then we recursively traverse the DOM tree Xerces creates, and for each node encountered, we allocate one of our own objects which contain localisation-specific information for that node, and then we bind it to the DOMNode object Xerces creates for each element using the setUserData function.

For a 6000 element XML document it takes 45 seconds for this process to complete. 5-10 seconds is our target.

Comment: I should also add that the tool we develop is a software localisation application. A lot of our clients are blue-chip companies who feel it's ok to throw all their localisation content into colossal XML files whereas something like JSON or even CSV might be more appropriate.

Comment: You say you can't allocate a big chunk because you need to initialize it -- why can't you use placement new to initialize it as needed?